# intermittent Bad Gateway 502 response in a particular enviroment

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, load-balancing, azure-load-balancer

We have a service implmented in WCF. It works fine in all environment except in a particular environment it often throws below exception

> System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: The remote server returned an unexpected response: (502) Bad Gateway.
>   System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (502) Bad Gateway.    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)...

The called methods return a Boolean value. But it is a big transaction which takes time on DB end often 15 mins. Our configuration is done for 50 mins.
Sometime is completes the transaction. Sometime it throws above error just after 2 minutes.

On the target machine there are load balancers involve. I have doubt that is error is because of them.

If the reason is so.. then what are my options??

Comment: A HTTP request/response transaction should not take more than a few seconds to complete. If a request starts off a long-running operation (like a heavy DB query or data processing job) then it should assign a handle to the job and return the handle to the HTTP client so they can poll the job status at their discretion. Live event responses in HTTP should be done with WebSockets or an RFC-compliant HTTP `EventSource` implementation.

Comment: Can you refer some link regarding the handle concept

Comment: You may also consider a duplex service, where the server will call the client back with the operation result once it is completed.